# Remove page numbers from string

Tags: c#, regex

So I am supplied with Index files from various books and my goal is to extract keywords from these files. Below are the test cases that I have observed.

```
1,3-dichlorobenzene  3, 6
2,3,4,6-tetrachlorophenol  13
3-D Analyst  178
Alabama 1
ArcView  82, 161-170, 173-174, 178-179, 181, 185
    3-D Analyst  178
    Spatial Analyst  178, 185
NH3  48, 56                     see also ammonia
aluminum sulfate, Al2(SO4)3   159
calibration  32,  50-51, 58, 78, 84-86, 88, 103,  116, 118123, 139,   141, 144-155,  208, 221-222, 226-227,  233,  236,  243, 257,  259-261, 
channel  1-3, 99, 100, 102-103, 106, 120, 144, 208-209, 220, 222, 228, 236-         239, 246, 275, 295, 18, 320-328, 331, 337, 341
```

For me it is important to preserve white space preceding the keyword as I am using it to determine hierarchy.

After removing page numbers this is what I need

```
1,3-dichlorobenzene  
2,3,4,6-tetrachlorophenol  
3-D Analyst  
Alabama 
ArcView  
    3-D Analyst  
    Spatial Analyst  
NH3                             see also ammonia
aluminum sulfate, Al2(SO4)3      
calibration  
channel
```

Currently I am doing this with two sets of regular expressions.

1. `var numbers_numbers = new Regex(@"(\s+\d{1,9}\-+\s*\d{1,9},?)");`
2. `var numbers = new Regex(@"(\s+\d{1,9},?)");`

```
 1. Step 1 will remove all the numbers of the format number-number, (example 173-174,) and  
 2. Step 2 will remove all the numbers of the format number,number (example 178, 185)
```

However my second regular expression does mess up my data too and this is what I get after replacement.

```
1,3-dichlorobenzene  
2,3,4,6-tetrachlorophenol  
3-D Analyst  
Alabama 
ArcView  
    **-D Analyst**  
    Spatial Analyst  
NH3                             see also ammonia
aluminum sulfate, Al2(SO4)3
calibration  
channel
```

Notice that 3 is missing from 3-D Analyst. I have also tried below regular expression

```
numbers = new Regex(@"(\s+\d{1,9}(?![^a-z\-]+),?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This fails to remove numbers from the first test case and gives back "1,3-dichlorobenzene  3"

```
numbers = new Regex(@"(\s+\d{1,9}[^a-z\-]+,?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

This fails "Alabama 1" test case and gives back "Alabama 1".

I think I am close to solving this but I am not sure what I am missing. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you process each line separately, then the following regex will do:

```
(?<!^[\d\s,]*)(?<!\w|\))\d+\s*(-\s*\d+)?,?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

```
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(?<!^[\d\s,]*)(?<!\w|\))\d+\s*(-\s*\d+)?,?", string.Empty);
```

Comment: This is so close. It doesn't work for "NH3  48, 56\t\t\t\t\t\tsee also ammonia" and "aluminum sulfate, Al2(SO4)" changing chemical formula is a big no :)

Comment: https://www.debuggex.com/ is pretty cool.  I didn't realize this question was in C#.  Thought it was in PHP...

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov could you please let me know how you generated image for the regular expression and do you use any tool for troubleshooting regular expression? You look like a pro at Regular expression :)

Comment: @user1477388 Because @ dcastro removed C# from my question's title :)

Comment: @ndd user1477388 already mentioned [debuggex.com](http://debuggex.com), the useful one for debugging and image generation.

Answer (score 1):

You may or may not like my solution to this problem; but it appears your page numbers are always preceeded by a double-space.  So, to remove the page numbers, just explode first by line, then by double space and take the first element of the array like so:

Here is some quick and dirty code I wrote for you:

```
$str = '1,3-dichlorobenzene  3, 6
2,3,4,6-tetrachlorophenol  13
3-D Analyst  178
Alabama 1
ArcView  82, 161-170, 173-174, 178-179, 181, 185
    3-D Analyst  178
    Spatial Analyst  178, 185
NH3  48, 56                     see also ammonia
aluminum sulfate, Al2(SO4)3   159
calibration  32,  50-51, 58, 78, 84-86, 88, 103,  116, 118123, 139,   141, 144-155,  208, 221-222, 226-227,  233,  236,  243, 257,  259-261, 
channel  1-3, 99, 100, 102-103, 106, 120, 144, 208-209, 220, 222, 228, 236-         239, 246, 275, 295, 18, 320-328, 331, 337, 341';

$str = str_replace('    ', '', $str);

$arr = explode("\r\n", $str);
//print_r($arr);
$final = array();

// phase 1

foreach ($arr as $item)
{
    $_arr = explode('  ', $item);
    $final[] = $_arr[0];
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($final);
$final2 = array();

// phase 2
foreach ($final as $item)
{
    $final2[] = preg_replace('/[0-9](?![A-Z])\,*\-?/', '', $item);
}

//print_r($final2);
```

The output is this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1,3-dichlorobenzene
    [1] => 2,3,4,6-tetrachlorophenol
    [2] => 3-D Analyst
    [3] => Alabama 1
    [4] => ArcView
    [5] => 3-D Analyst
    [6] => Spatial Analyst
    [7] => NH3
    [8] => aluminum sulfate, Al2(SO4)3
    [9] => calibration
    [10] => channel
)
```

You'll see all numbers, dashes and commas are removed leaving only the titles:

Comment: I think you are right for most of the cases. I did notice couple of odd cases in file where they are not followed by double spaces

Comment: Yeah since the data is "dirty" it's gonna be hard to program something to solve every scenario.  You may want to clean it up before running it through.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts unfortunately it does mess up data check the formula for aluminum sulfate in your answer and I will loose "see also XXXX"

Comment: I re-read your question.  How about my edit?  This closely matches what you've requested in your original question.

Comment: As soon as I split it I will loose "see also XXXX" that's the main reason I would like to avoid split. Also in your second answer you would notice it is missing "3-D Analyst" and "Spatial Analyst" I can't skip words from the index :)

Comment: This is why I am trying to explain you need to clean up your data.  Please see my final edit.  See how both "3-D Analyst" and "Spatial Analyst" are now included.

Comment: I have around 520 files to process if I start up cleaning them it will be my nightmare :) also as mentioned in my question I can't remove spaces preceding contents as I need them for hierarchy. Though thank you so much for your efforts :)

Comment: If indeed you need the spaces for hierarchy, just replace them with a special character that you can find later, like `{NESTED_ITEM}`, so you can loop through and do what you need to do later.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question right, this should do it

```
numbers = new Regex(@"(\s+\d{1,9},{1,9}[^a-z\-]+,?)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: I tried but this doesn't work and gives me below output 

- 2,3,4,6-tetrachlorophenol  13
- 3-D Analyst  178

I think it is because last number doesn't have "," followed by another number.